# How to umount file.tar.bz (that was mounted with archivemount) without needing sudo

Tags: fstab, umount, file-archiver

As a regular user I mount my archive files with this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARCHIVEF=$(zenity --file-selection --filename=/shared/);
archivemount $ARCHIVEF /media/archivemount/
```

Unfortunately, sudo is required to umount. That doesn't work well for me. I would like a way to umount without sudo. I can get fstab changes made. I'm just not sure what changes to make there. Or other options are welcome too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to unmount using `$ fusermount -u /media/archivemount` (or whatever the mountpoint is).